# failed to open image in ROS Kinetic

Tags: dictionary, mapping, ros, uwb

[hello, i have run this  "roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch" in ROS Kinetic but its turn out "failed to open image file"  image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhwuP.png)

I'm expecting to display the map

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the correct path to the map.pgm file is not being passed to ROS. I can see the problem with the path happening in the map.yaml file.

Navigate to turtlebot3 -> turtlebot3_navigation -> maps -> map.yaml and change the first line from `image: ./map.pgm` to `image: map.pgm`.

This should allow for the map image to be loaded correctly.